Hybrid VPN setup with WireGuard
I currently have ServerInternal (192.168.1.0/24) IP range, and ServerExternal (which is a virtual machine at a provider). I want to setup a site-to-site VPN between ServerInternal and ServerExternal where they both have connectivity. I then would like Windows clients to connect to ServerExternal and reach the ServerInternal (192.168.1.0/24) IP space. I currently have the following configuration, and I am able to have connectivity between the site-to-site VPN, however the Windows clients are unable to reach the 192.168.1.0/24 IP space. My configurations and statements I run are below:
ServerExternal
[Interface]
PrivateKey = KEY_HERE
Address = 10.0.0.1/24
ListenPort = 51820
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -A FORWARD -o %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -D FORWARD -o %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

[Peer]
PublicKey = KEY_FOR_INTERNAL_HERE
AllowedIPs = 192.168.1.0/24
PersistentKeepalive = 5

[Peer]
PublicKey = KEY_FOR_WINDOWS_CLIENT_HERE
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.3/32
PersistentKeepalive = 5

ServerInternal
[Interface]
PrivateKey = KEY_HERE
Address = 10.0.0.2/24
ListenPort = 51820
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -A FORWARD -o %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -D FORWARD -o %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

[Peer]
PublicKey = KEY_FOR_EXTERNAL_HERE
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
Endpoint = 172.233.145.16:51820
PersistentKeepalive = 5

Windows Client
[Interface]
PrivateKey = KEY_HERE
Address = 10.0.0.3/24

[Peer]
PublicKey = KEY_FOR_EXTERNAL_HERE
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.1/32, 192.168.1.0/24
Endpoint = 172.233.145.16:51820
PersistentKeepalive = 25



Run ip address on ServerInternal to make sure eth0 is the name of its 192.168.1.0/24 interface. 2. Run sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward on ServerExternal & Internal to make sure you've turned on packet forwarding. 3. Run sudo iptables-save & sudo nft list ruleset on ServerExternal & Internal to check if you have other firewall rules blocking forwarding.

